# Nodejs asynchronus callbacks and recursion

Tags: node.js, recursion, path, directory, fs

I would like to do something like this

```
function scan(apath){
    var files = fs.readdirSync(apath);
    for(var i=0; i<files.length;i++){
        var stats = fs.statSync(path.join(apath,files[i]))
        if(stats.isDirectory()){
            results.push(path.join(apath, files[i]))
            scan(path.join(apath,files[i]))
        }
        if(stats.isFile()){
            results.push(path.join(apath,files[i]))
        }
    }
}
```

but asynchronously.

Trying this with asynchronous functions led me to a nightmare with something like this.

```
function scan(apath){
    fs.readdir(apath, function(err, files)){
        var counter = files.length;
        files.forEach(function(file){
            var newpath = path.join(apath, file)
            fs.stat(newpath, function(err, stat){
                if(err) return callback(err)
                if(stat.isFile())
                    results.push(newpath)
                if(stat.isDirectory()){
                    results.push(newpath)
                    scan(newpath)
                }
                if(--counter <=0) return

            })
        })
    }
}
```

All hell breaks loose in node's stack because things don't happen in logical succession as they do in synchronous methods.

Answer (score 0):

you can try async module, and use like this:

```
function scan(apath, callback) {
    fs.readdir(apath, function(err, files) {
        var counter = 0;
        async.whilst(
            function() {
                return counter < files.length;
            },
            function(cb) {
                var file = files[counter++];
                var newpath = path.join(apath, file);
                fs.stat(newpath, function(err, stat) {
                    if (err) return cb(err);
                    if (stat.isFile()) {
                        results.push(newpath);
                        cb(); // asynchronously call the loop
                    }
                    if (stat.isDirectory()) {
                        results.push(newpath);
                        scan(newpath, cb); // recursion loop
                    }
                });
            },
            function(err) {
                callback(err); // loop over, come out
            }
        );
    });
}
```

look for more about [async.whilst](https://github.com/caolan/async#whilst)